# The type or namespace 'WebImage' could not be found

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I set up a new ASP.NET project in VS2012 (using Razor).
However I have an issue with "WebImage" object.. I get the error mentionned in title when I put this code into a cshtml page:

```
@{  
WebImage photo = null;
}
```

I thought that WebImage type were natively present in an ASP.Net project..

I don't know what to do in order to solve the issue..

Comment: What kind of "Image" you need? the asp.net Image control? The Image object (representing an image file usually)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is not accessible from your project but it is present in System.WebHelpers maybe you have removed the reference to it somehow, adding this reference back in should solve the issue for you.

Comment: I meant as a reference in the project to System.Web.Helpers.dll

Comment: Look under the references folder of the project, it the reference is not present, then right click and choose add reference, then look for it in the Assemblies section

Comment: OK..Just added System.Web.Helpers extension (v2.0) but still have the same error